# AVPlayer autoplays but should not (Swift)

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I’ve created a very simple AVPlayer within a macOS app.

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet var playerView: AVPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "myPath/myFile.mp4")
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoPath)
    playerView.player = videoPlayer

    }

}
```

It basically works fine, but the player plays automatically on launch, which it should not. Even when I add `playerView.player?.pause()` at the end of `viewDidLoad`, it autoplays.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least put your `AVPlayer` in the `ViewWillAppear()` function, and pausing `playerView.player` would pause your entire view — instead pause `videoPlayer`:

```
videoPlayer.pause()
```

Adding that after `playerView.player = videoPlayer` should work; your code would then be:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    let videoPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "myPath/myFile.mp4")
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoPath)
    playerView.player = videoPlayer
    videoPlayer.pause()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Code works fine in `viewWillAppear`, and even without the `.pause()` line the video does not autoplays now. Could you please explain why that makes the difference?

Comment: `ViewDIdLoad` loads whether the view has loaded or not, whereas `ViewWillAppear` is called when the view has been fully transitioned onto the screen, meaning it is not "hidden", does not have a hidden ancestor, and is in a window that's ordered in — the default behavior is to do nothing.